# Non-static method Illuminate\Routing\Route::middleware() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have encountered this error in this file  : route/api.php 
This error refers to line 16

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
    |
    */

   16- Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request::user();
    });
    Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login');
```

Comment: what is error message?

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved by changing this line

from

```
 use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the method `middleware` is not static method, according to the [assigning-middleware-to-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) try it like this:

```php
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request::user();
    })->middleware('auth:api');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since You've not defined in Your question what is error message I can only predict that You're using middleware incorrectly.

Middleware should be assigned to group.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
  Router::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request::user();
  });
});
```

or You've to use middleware after defining the route handler:

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request) {
  return $request::user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```